# Replacing the deprecated function the_meta

Tags: custom-field, deprecation

the_meta is deprecated and it's told to replace it with get_post_meta.
I'm using since long time this function for custom fields without styles:
//the_meta function without styles:

```
function mymeta() {
if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {

        foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
            $keyt = trim($key);
            if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
                continue;
            $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
            $value = implode(', ', $values);
            echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "$key $value \n", $key, $value);
        }

    };
```

But I don't know how to replace it with get_post_meta ().
I was using the mymeta function to list all the custom fields of a post for special purposes. And get_post_meta() retrieve just the value of a single custom field of a post.

The code where I use than "mymeta ()":

```
<?php $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=22&category_name=gigs&post_status=future&order=ASC&orderby=date'); foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?><div> <h2 style=""><?php the_time('l \&\n\b\s\p\; j. F \'y');?><?php mymeta();?></h2> <h1><br /><?php the_title(); ?><br /></h1>
```

Any help welcome.
thanx in advance & cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) to retrieve all meta data for a post, by leaving the third and fourth parameters empty.

> $meta_key string Optional Metadata key. If not specified, retrieve all metadata for the specified object.

```php
get_metadata( 'post', $post_id );
```

Comment: Thanx Caleb, but I didn't got it to work /replace it with get_metadata ().
I use costum fields with several Names, and each post is using one of them with its own value.... In my case: starting time of a show and Value: the location with address